# App crashes with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object" and asynTask error

Tags: android

Problem: When I move from activitycart to another page (after adding an item) and just come back to Mycart again and delete the item my app crashes giving the error below. I understand that when I move out of Activitycart it closes the db_order and when I return and delete anything it tries to perform an operation on already closed database. Also it gives asyntask error thereafter.But I am new to android and don't know how & where to fix there error. Any help please.

Error:

```
DB ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/twik.in/databases/db_order
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/twik.in/databases/db_order
W/System.err:at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
W/System.err:at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1494)
W/System.err:at twik.in.DBHelper.deleteAllData(DBHelper.java:230)
W/System.err:at twik.in.ActivityCart$4.onClick(ActivityCart.java:212)
W/System.err:at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
W/System.err:at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W/System.err:at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: twik.in, PID: 5477
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/twik.in/databases/db_order
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1158)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
at twik.in.DBHelper.getAllData(DBHelper.java:123)
at twik.in.ActivityCart.getDataFromDatabase(ActivityCart.java:378)
at twik.in.ActivityCart$getDataTask.doInBackground(ActivityCart.java:350)
at twik.in.ActivityCart$getDataTask.doInBackground(ActivityCart.java:335)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Activitycart.java

```
package twik.in;
public class ActivityCart extends Activity {

// declare view objects
//  ImageButton imgNavBack;
ListView listOrder;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
TextView txtTotalLabel, txtTotal, txtAlert;
Button btnClear, Checkout;
RelativeLayout lytOrder;

// declate dbhelper and adapter objects
DBHelper dbhelper;
AdapterCart mola;


// declare static variables to store tax and currency data
static double Tax;
static String Currency;

// declare arraylist variable to store data
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data;
static ArrayList<Integer> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<String> Menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<Integer> Quantity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Double> Sub_total_price = new ArrayList<Double>();

double Total_price;
final int CLEAR_ALL_ORDER = 0;
final int CLEAR_ONE_ORDER = 1;
int FLAG;
int ID;
String TaxCurrencyAPI;
int IOConnect = 0;

// create price format
DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_order);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
    bar.setTitle("Order Detail");
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // connect view objects with xml id
//        imgNavBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgNavBack);
    Checkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Checkout);
    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    listOrder = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrder);
    txtTotalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotalLabel);
    txtTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);
    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);
    btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    lytOrder = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lytOrder);

    // tax and currency API url
    TaxCurrencyAPI = Constant.TaxCurrencyAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey;

    mola = new AdapterCart(this);
    dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);

    // open database
    try{
        dbhelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }

    // call asynctask class to request tax and currency data from server
    new getTaxCurrency().execute();

    // event listener to handle clear button when clicked
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // show confirmation dialog
            showClearDialog(CLEAR_ALL_ORDER, 1111);
        }
    });

    // event listener to handle list when clicked
    listOrder.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // show confirmation dialog
            showClearDialog(CLEAR_ONE_ORDER, Menu_ID.get(position));
        }
    });

    // event listener to handle back button when clicked
//imgNavBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
//public void onClick(View arg0) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              // close database and back to previous page
//              dbhelper.close();
//              finish();
//              overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
//          }
//      });

    Checkout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // close database and back to previous page
            dbhelper.close();
            Intent iReservation = new Intent(ActivityCart.this, ActivityCheckout.class);
            startActivity(iReservation);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// method to create dialog
void showClearDialog(int flag, int id){
    FLAG = flag;
    ID = id;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =   new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm);
    switch(FLAG){
    case 0:
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.clear_all_order));
        break;
    case 1:
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.clear_one_order));
        break;
    }
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(FLAG){
            case 0:
                // clear all menu in order table
                dbhelper.deleteAllData();
                listOrder.invalidateViews();
                clearData();
                new getDataTask().execute();
                break;
            case 1:
                // clear selected menu in order table
                dbhelper.deleteData(ID);
                listOrder.invalidateViews();
                clearData();
                new getDataTask().execute();
                break;
            }

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // close dialog
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getTaxCurrency extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    // show progressbar first
    getTaxCurrency(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // parse json data from server in background
        parseJSONDataTax();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        // if internet connection available request data form server
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if(IOConnect == 0){
            new getDataTask().execute();
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setText(R.string.alert);
        }

    }
}

// method to parse json data from server
public void parseJSONDataTax(){

    try {
        // request data from tax and currency API
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(TaxCurrencyAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }

        // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        JSONObject object_tax = data.getJSONObject(0); 
        JSONObject tax = object_tax.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

        Tax = Double.parseDouble(tax.getString("Value"));

        JSONObject object_currency = data.getJSONObject(1); 
        JSONObject currency = object_currency.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

        Currency = currency.getString("Value");


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

// clear arraylist variables before used
void clearData(){
    Menu_ID.clear();
    Menu_name.clear();
    Quantity.clear();
    Sub_total_price.clear();
}

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    // show progressbar first
    getDataTask(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            lytOrder.setVisibility(8);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // get data from database
        getDataFromDatabase();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // show data
        txtTotal.setText( Total_price+" "+Currency);
        txtTotalLabel.setText(getString(R.string.total_order)+" ("+Tax+"% XTRAOFF)");
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        // if data available show data on list
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if(Menu_ID.size() > 0){
            lytOrder.setVisibility(0);
            listOrder.setAdapter(mola);
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }

    }
}

// method to get data from server
public void getDataFromDatabase(){

    Total_price = 0;
    clearData();
    data = dbhelper.getAllData();

    // store data to arraylist variables
    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
        ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(i);

        Menu_ID.add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(0).toString()));
        Menu_name.add(row.get(1).toString());
        Quantity.add(Integer.parseInt(row.get(2).toString()));
        Sub_total_price.add(Double.parseDouble(formatData.format(Double.parseDouble(row.get(3).toString()))));
        Total_price += Sub_total_price.get(i);
    }

    // count total order
    Total_price -= (Total_price * (Tax/100));
    Total_price = Double.parseDouble(formatData.format(Total_price));
}

// when back button pressed close database and back to previous page
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    dbhelper.close();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
{
    // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}}
```

DBhelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

String DB_PATH;
private final static String DB_NAME = "db_order";
public final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static SQLiteDatabase db; 

private final Context context;

private final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_order";
private final String ID = "id";
private final String MENU_NAME = "Menu_name";
private final String QUANTITY = "Quantity";
private final String TOTAL_PRICE = "Total_price";


public DBHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.context = context;

    DB_PATH = Constant.DBPath;
}   

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;


    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist

    }else{
        db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db_Read.close();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

}



private boolean checkDataBase(){

    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

    return dbFile.exists();

}


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public void close() {
    if(db!=null)
        db.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

/** this code is used to get all data from database */
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllData(){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

    Cursor cursor = null;

        try{
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{ID, MENU_NAME, QUANTITY, TOTAL_PRICE},
                    null,null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                do{
                    ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));

                    dataArrays.add(dataList);
                }

                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return dataArrays;
}

/** this code is used to get all data from database */
public boolean isDataExist(long id){
    boolean exist = false;

    Cursor cursor = null;

        try{
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{ID},
                    ID +"="+id,
                    null, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                exist = true;
            }

            cursor.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return exist;
}

/** this code is used to get all data from database */
public boolean isPreviousDataExist(){
    boolean exist = false;

    Cursor cursor = null;

        try{
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{ID},
                    null,null, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                exist = true;
            }

            cursor.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return exist;
}

public void addData(long id, String menu_name, int quantity, double total_price){
    // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, id);
    values.put(MENU_NAME, menu_name);
    values.put(QUANTITY, quantity);
    values.put(TOTAL_PRICE, total_price);

    // ask the database object to insert the new data 
    try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void deleteData(long id){
    // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
    try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + "=" + id, null);}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void deleteAllData(){
    // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
    try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateData(long id, int quantity, double total_price){
    // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(QUANTITY, quantity);
    values.put(TOTAL_PRICE, total_price);

    // ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
    try {db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + "=" + id, null);}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must get writable database before you perform any transaction in db
at twik.in.ActivityCart.getDataFromDatabase(ActivityCart.java:378)

so open the database before you do a db operation and close it as soon as possible.
example

```
switch(FLAG){
        case 0:
            // clear all menu in order table
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
            dbhelper.deleteAllData();
            dbhelper.close();
            listOrder.invalidateViews();
            clearData();
            new getDataTask().execute();
            break;
        case 1:
            // clear selected menu in order table
            dbhelper.openDataBase();
            dbhelper.deleteData(ID);
            dbhelper.close();
            listOrder.invalidateViews();
            clearData();
            new getDataTask().execute();
            break;
        }
```

Note : you must close your db as soon as you complete your transaction or else your app may throw database object leaked exception if you keep your db open for so long.

Comment: Great. Thanks for helping me out buddy. It solved the problem.